# Selecting Multiple Rows in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, date

I use a massive tracker that stores the dates on which sites have been built. I am trying to look through a range of cells and determine if the date is today's date. I wrote a tiny Excel sheet to make it less complicated before implementing in my tracker.

This is what I am working with.

[image: Excel Screenshot]

The problem is that it only selects one line with today's date when there are more.

This is the selection that Excel makes when the button is pressed.

[image: Excel Selection]

How do I select more than one row? (They might not be next to each other. It might be row 1, 5, and 8 in the future).

```
'   Date Selection Macro
'   Goal! - Bring automated cell selection based on date range
'   TODO - Create macro to select rows that have a given date range
'   TODO - Create a window that allows you to add the given date range 
'   rather than hard code
'   TODO - Export selected rows to an email template in Outlook

Sub DateSelection()
    Dim completionDate As Range
    Set completionDate = Range("B2:B8")

    Dim todaysDate As Date
    todaysDate = Date

    For Each cell In completionDate
        If cell = todaysDate Then
            cell.EntireRow.Select
        Else
            'cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You need `Union` like this:

```
Sub DateSelection()

  Dim completionDate As Range
  Set completionDate = Range("B2:B8")
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim todaysDate As Date
  todaysDate = Date

  For Each cell In completionDate

      If cell = todaysDate Then
          If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = cell.EntireRow
          Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, cell.EntireRow)
          End If
      Else
          'cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3

  End If

  Next
  rng.Select
End Sub
```

However, you also could use filter to only show rows with todays date and then select all that is shown. Would do the same :)

Comment: That worked like a charm Dirk! I am just trying to understand how lol. Why are you checking if the range is Nothing? Again, excuse the elementary questions lol.

Comment: Just to avoid errors. if `rng` is empty, union will fail and an error message will pop up :)

Comment: Thanks Dirk! Much appreciated sir!